# What do I do with Indaryn's Gold Necklace in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I have "Indaryn's Gold Necklace". It's marked as a quest item so I can't drop it. What do I do with it?

A google search for the item name yields *zero* hits. All of the Skyrim wikis seem to be completely silent on the topic. Does anyone have any idea?

This is Skyrim on PS3, with all the latest patches at the time of this posting.

Comment: May be a item you have to plant in another house, I remember doing this with a couple items. Check through your quest log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears it was either wanted by Sergius Turrianus in the Mages College in Winterhold. The quest was under miscellaneous as "Return the Item". After talking to him, it said "Indaryn's Gold Necklace removed" and that was that.

Looking at the wiki for the quests related to Sergius, it appears that this was randomly generated by the Radiant Quest system, so it makes sense that not everyone who plays will get "Indaryn's Gold Necklace". Instead they will get some other random NPCs random item.

Mystery solved!

Answer (score 1):

You are a thief, you stole the necklace and for some reason Devin or Vex did not want it. I have had this happen a few times and I am not sure the cause. I think it may have something to do with being the last theft required to get the special mission in a specific town but this is just conjecture at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference to "Indaryn" in [Riften](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Miscellaneous_Quests) (search for Indaryn there). Have you tried heading over to Riften and talking to Indaryn?

Do you remember where you found it?

Comment: Yeah, Indaryn himself is not hard to find. He is the manager of the Black-Briar Meadary, but he doesn't say anything about his necklace. I don't actually remember how I got it (possibly pick-pocketing it, or taking it from his room?). I just can't find any reference to his necklace or why it would be marked as a quest item.